# Get only a part of a string using PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I use the following code

```
foreach ($twitter_xml2->channel->item as $key) {
    $author = $key->{"guid"};
    echo"<li><h5>$author</h5></li>";
}
```

and it gets me `http://twitter.com/USERNAME/statuses/167382363782206976`

My question is how do I get only the username ?

**Username may be anything**

Comment: `$key->{"guid"}` is equivalent to `$key->guid` by the way. You don't need the `{""}` around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = "http://twitter.com/USERNAME/statuses/167382363782206976"
preg_match("#http://twitter.com/([^\/]+)/statuses/.*#", $url, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: change `([^\/])` to `([^\/]+)`

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($twitter_xml2->channel->item as $key) {
    $author = $key->{"guid"};
    list(,,,$username) = explode('/', $author);
    echo"<li><h5>$username</h5></li>";
}
```

Comment: Can you post me the entire block. Btw the "Username" may be anything

Comment: This will work if username is anything but "/" and slash count before the username doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either this regexp (for [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)): `~twitter\.com/([^/]+)/~`:

```
$match = array();
preg_match( '~twitter\.com/([^/]+)/~', $url, $match);
echo $match[1]; // list(,$userName) = $match;
```

Or more effective [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$start = strpos( $url, '/', 10); // say 10th character is after http:// and before .com/
$end = strpos( $url, '/', $start+1); // This would be the end
// Check both idexes
$username = substr( $url, $start, $end-$start);
// you will maybe have to fix indexes +/-1
```